# SKAudioNode only playing Musics in Mono

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaudionode

I'm developing a `SpriteKit` game, and I encountered a problem: The `SKAudioNode` instance only plays my game's background music in mono mode.

I have the following instance in my `SKScene` class:

```
var backgroundMusic : SKAudioNode?
```

The following method loads and plays the background music:

```
func loadAndPlayBackgroundMusic() {
    if let musicURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "music", withExtension: "mp3") {
        backgroundMusic = SKAudioNode(url: musicURL)
        self.addChild(self.backgroundMusic!)
    } else {
        print("Error: Could not load the music!")
    }
}
```

It plays the music just fine, the only problem is that it seems to be mono (or using some sort of 3D spatial audio effect). How can I fix it?
I already trying setting the `SKAudioNode's` `isPositional` property to `false` with no avail.

Comment: did you try to use another mp3 to check if you have the same weird effect?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Yes! It's not the mp3 file.

Comment: Have you considered using `SKAction.playSoundFileNamed` or `AVAudioPlayer` instead? They both work with stereo files.